# GWT-GAE: Error: NOT_FOUND after deploying an app

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I tried to deploy my application, which also stores data in the datastore in app engine. I use the objectify library for accessing the datastore. Locally it runs without problems, and I can acces the admin datastore locally. But when I try to deploy it, although eclipse says that it has been successfully deployed, when I try the url, I get an error: NOT_FOUND.
In the log(in the app engine) there are two warnings:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter getWriteObjectifyKeyAsStringModule: Exception while resolving Objectify Key#getString
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.googlecode.objectify.Key.getString()
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-16096d3fb5bf337e(Request.java)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:216)
at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.getWriteObjectifyKeyAsStringModule(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:154)
at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.<init>(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:57)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.getResponseWriter(SystemServiceServlet.java:127)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:107)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

and

```
com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader getObjectifyKeyModule: Exception while resolving Objectify Key#create
       java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.googlecode.objectify.Key.create(java.lang.String)
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-16096d3fb5bf337e(Request.java)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:216)
at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.getObjectifyKeyModule(ServletRequestParamReader.java:147)
at com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader.<init>(ServletRequestParamReader.java:131)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.getParamReader(SystemServiceServlet.java:122)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:140)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
```

I have 4 rpc methods that look like a lot so I'm going to put an example of one of them:

the greetingService:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("registration")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    String greetServer(String email, String pass, String rPass, int job ) throws IllegalArgumentException;

}
```

the Async:

```
public interface GreetingServiceAsync {
    void greetServer(String email, String pass, String rPass, int job, AsyncCallback<String> callback) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

and the Impl:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(LoginUser.class);
    }

    public String greetServer(String email, String pass, String rPass, int job) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();

        LoginUser user = new LoginUser();

        if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(email)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name must be at least 4 characters long");
        }
        if (!FieldVerifier.isValidPass(pass, rPass)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password and Repeat Password do not match!");
        } else {
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setPassword(pass);
            user.setJob(job);
            ofy.put(user);
        }

        return email;
    }
}
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried google? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/mH6ixzjBrJA or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988409/error-not-found-google-apps-eng

Comment: Yes, I saw them, but they don't provide any help.

Comment: error on server ? any stacktrace ?

Comment: This is the message from the log: "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out what the problem was. I just reinstall gwt and gae, created a new project and I was able to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I realized that I had objectify-3.0.jar in my war/WEB-INF/lib 
The Key.getString() method apparently was added to version 3.1 only, so after I replaced objectify-3.0.jar with objectify-3.1.jar the problem was gone.